# Php Gallery best practice as a performance to display images

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, gallery, lightbox

I have a table where I save the photos that the user uploads by year and week number (I have to save on DB instead of on file).

How do I set the display of these photos? I can have the year selected but I don't know how many photos will be present ... how do I view them?

I load e.g. 10 and then via scroll ajax load the others? Should I display thumbnails and then when user click on it he see the original image? I would have problems if I used lightbox for the gallery in this way?

What is the correct way to proceed in order not to have performance problems?

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: @ArmanGin I haven't written any code yet because I want to understand which is the best approach